# How do I use D3 to I populate drop-down options from JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tags

I'm populating a select tag using D3 to append the options from a JSON string.  I don't see the options getting appended to the select tag when I launch the page.  I don't believe I'm accessing the data correctly and need guidance on what I'm doing wrong.

I've confirmed that the JSON data is retrieved by the d3.json() function but after that, I'm not sure about how to access the data.

JSON

```
{"iyear":{"0":1970,"1":1971,"2":1972,"3":1973,"4":1974,"5":1975,"6":1976,"7":1977,"8":1978,"9":1979,"10":1980,"11":1981,"12":1982,"13":1983,"14":1984,"15":1985,"16":1986,"17":1987,"18":1988,"19":1989,"20":1990,"21":1991,"22":1992,"23":1994,"24":1995,"25":1996,"26":1997,"27":1998,"28":1999,"29":2000,"30":2001,"31":2002,"32":2003,"33":2004,"34":2005,"35":2006,"36":2007,"37":2008,"38":2009,"39":2010,"40":2011,"41":2012,"42":2013,"43":2014,"44":2015,"45":2016,"46":2017}}
```

JavaScript

```
d3.json("/named/").then((iyear) => {
    iyear.forEach((iyear) => {
        selector.append("option")
        .text(function (i) { return i.iyear; })
        .property("value", iyear);
    });
});
```

I want when I click on the dropdown that I see an option for each year in the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

The d3 way is to select not parent element, but elements themselves (even if they're not created just yet) and combine them with data. The creation of new elements is the decided later by working with `enter` selection.

I'm not sure how you can call forEach on an object, but even so, using function for setting value (like you do for `.text`) won't work, because the way you create option tags they have no data bound to them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <select></select>
  <script>
    var optionsData = [{
      value: '0',
      text: '1970'
    }, {
      value: '1',
      text: '1971'
    }];

    var selectTag = d3.select("select");

    //we have select all options tags from inside select tag (which there are 0 atm)
    //and assigned data as to be the base of modelling that selection.
    var options = selectTag.selectAll('option')
      .data(optionsData);

    //d3 sees we have less elements (0) than the data (2), so we are tasked to create
    //these missing inside the `options.enter` pseudo selection.
    //if we had some elements from before, they would be reused, and we could access their
    //selection with just `options`
    options.enter()
      .append('option')
      .attr('value', function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.text;
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Ultimately, if that's all you want to do, I'd argue against using d3. It'd be easy to do the json fetch and this simple options creationg even with plain js. D3's value shows when you're dealing with more complex logic.